# Can you start a sentence with “her”?

Tags: pronouns, verb-agreement, grammatical-case, sentence-starts

Can someone please answer this burning question? Is the following sentence correct?

> **Her** and her voice were truly a gift.

Answer (score 5):

This *her* is not strictly correct, but that isn't because it is the first word in the sentence, but rather because it is part of the subject. In informal English, I suppose this might be OK; but, according to convention, it should be *she and her voice were truly a gift*.

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously start a sentence with "her". For example:

> Her voice was truly a gift.

But I suspect that is not what you are asking.

Some people will insist that you must say "She and her voice ..." (and "I and John ...", etc). However, in practice, particularly for the spoken language, this is not always the case. There are complex rules governing what is a "natural" use of coordinated pronouns.

I am sure that many people would find your example acceptable (ignoring the peevers).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it makes much sense in that specific context to be honest. I'd go with something like "She was a true gift, as much as her voice" or something like that.